# Module pyautoguy doesn't write the @ symbol

Tags: python, module, pyautogui

i was doing a program that create a random string and after that there is @gmail.com

```
stringone=(random.choice(letters)+random.choice(letters)+"ab@gmail.com")
```

i need to typewrite with the pyautogui module the string so:

```
pyautogui.typewrite(stringone)
```

so seems quite simple but **it doesn't print only the @...**

Solutions?

*i tried to print ("\x40") that should be the @ symbol but t doesn't work too*

Comment: See the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53585433/how-to-type-using-pyautogui Basically pyautogui sends commands as if you were typing with your keyboard, so any character that would require more than one key to be pressed needs to be specified, see also here. https://pyautogui.readthedocs.io/en/latest/keyboard.html

Comment: I appreciate that you try to help me, unfortunally it doesn't work